# get the attribute that was created with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the data attribute content that was created by a jquery? (Refer below)

the html

```
<div data-number="1">
    <a href="#" class="element_with_a_data_attribute">element with a data attribute</a>
</div>
<div class="show_and_hide_element" data-idty="show">
    <a href="#" class="data_attribute_displayer">Click me to show the data attribute that exist in this parent element</a>
</div>
```

the script

```
//hide the show_and_hide_element
$('.show_and_hide_element').hide();
//if click the .element_with_a_data_attribute
$('.element_with_a_data_attribute').click(function(){
    //put its parent data attribute (data-number) into a variable named "datanumber"
    var datanumber = $(this).parent("div").attr("data-number");
    //then add the datanumber as a data attribute (data-number) to the div that has a class of "show_and_hide_element"
    $('.show_and_hide_element').attr("data-number", datanumber);
    //show the .show_and_hide_element div
    $(".show_and_hide_element").show();
});
//if click the data_attribute_displayer
$('.data_attribute_displayer').click(function(){
    //if the parent (div .show_and_hide_element) attribute named "data-idty" of this element is equal to show.
    if($(this).parent("div").attr("data-idty") === "show"){
        //popup (alert thing) the data number of its parent element (the div)
        alert($(this).parent().attr("data-number"));
    }
});
```

as you can see from the above code reference, if the link that has a class of element_with_a_data_attribute is click then it will get the attribute name data-number from its parent (the div that wrap this link) and then add its parent attribute to the div that has a class of show_and_hide_element and then next, if the link that has a class of data_attribute_displayer is click then it get its parent attribute named "data-number" that was added when the link that has a class of element_with_a_data_attribute is triggered but sadly, not working. Any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When the code runs, the elements that you try to bind events to doesn't exist yet. You need to run the code in the `ready` event, so that the elements exist.

Comment: [Your code seems to work just fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/bde2Lnr7/)

Comment: FYI you should always access `data-*` properties using jQuery's `.data()` method, not `attr()` as the attributes on the element may not be in sync with jQuery's data cache.

Comment: solve now thank you.